# How to get pdf page number with PDFBox

Tags: solr, pdfbox

I'm using a tool based on PDFBox for index PDF files and send it to Solr with the right data. What I'm trying to do is to let PDFBox get the page numbers of the PDF and index it to Solr. I need to create a way when I search for a specific keyword in Solr to have in the results also the page number where is my result. 
So I will need to get somehow the page number of the PDF.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String sdir = null;
        String dir = null;
        long pollingInterval = 10000;

        PrintStream startupOut = System.out;
        CommandLine cl = getCommandLine(startupOut, args);
        if (cl == null) {
            System.out.println("System exit. Your arguments was invalid. Please try again.");
            return;
        }

        if (!cl.hasOption('s')) {
            System.out.println("System exit. Your arguments was invalid. Please try again.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Welcome to use this program! This program is running as a service. To stop ctrl+c.");
        System.out.println("Monitoring is started");

        String dOption = cl.getOptionValue('d');
        if (cl.hasOption('d')) {
            dir = dOption;
        }

        if(dir != null) {

            if(dir.lastIndexOf("/") < dir.length() - 1)
                dir += "/";

            AnalysePdf.analysePdfFolder(dir);

            SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrServerUrl).build();

            FileUtil.allFiles.clear();
            List<File> htmlfiles = FileUtil.getFiles(new File(dir));

            if (htmlfiles.size() > 0) {

                for (File file : htmlfiles) {

                    if (!FileUtil.getFileType(file).equalsIgnoreCase("htm"))
                        continue;

                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
                    Elements headers = doc.select("p.header");

                    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    try {

                        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line.trim());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            br1.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    String content = sb.toString();
                    String fileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                    String year = fileName.substring(0, 4);
                    String month = fileName.substring(5, 7);
                    String version = "";

                    int len = fileName.length();
                    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                        if (fileName.substring(len - i, len - i + 1).equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
                            version = fileName.substring(len - i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    for (Element header : headers) {
                        String headerValue = header.text().trim();

                        if (!headerValue.equals("") && !headerValue.startsWith("http")) {

                            Element headerElement = header.nextElementSibling();
                            String text = headerElement.text();
                            if (headerElement.nextElementSibling() != null) {
                                if (headerElement.nextElementSibling().hasClass("text"))
                                    text += headerElement.nextElementSibling().text();
                            }

                            // Preparing the Solr document
                            SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

                            // Adding fields to the document
                            solrDoc.addField("content", content);
                            solrDoc.addField("paragraph_header", header.text());
                            solrDoc.addField("paragraph_txt", text);
                            solrDoc.addField("url", dir + file.getName().replaceAll("htm", "pdf"));
                            solrDoc.addField("year", year);
                            solrDoc.addField("month", month);
                            solrDoc.addField("version", version);

                            if(!version.equals(""))
                                solrDoc.addField("sorting", year + "_" + month + "_" + version);
                            else
                                solrDoc.addField("sorting", year + "_" + month);

                            solrDoc.addField("stream_size", file.length());
                            solrDoc.addField("resource_name", file.getName().replaceAll("htm", "pdf"));
                            solrDoc.addField("content_type", "pdf");

                            // Adding the document to Solr
                            solrClient.add(solrDoc);
                        }
                    }
                    if(file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Commiting...");

            // Saving the changes
            solrClient.commit();

            System.out.println("Completed!...");

        } else {

            String sOption = cl.getOptionValue('s');
            if (cl.hasOption('s')) {
                sdir = String.valueOf(sOption);
                if(sdir.lastIndexOf("/") < sdir.length() - 1)
                    sdir += "/";
                rootDir = sdir;
            }

            if(sdir != null) {
                File parentDir = new File(sdir).getParentFile();
                if(parentDir.exists())
                {
                    tmpDir = new File(parentDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "tmp");
                    if(!tmpDir.exists())
                        tmpDir.mkdir();
                }
            }

            String tOption = cl.getOptionValue('t');
            if (cl.hasOption('t')) {
                pollingInterval = Long.valueOf(tOption);
            }

            File folder = new File(sdir);

            if (!folder.exists()) {
                // Test to see if monitored folder exists
                throw new RuntimeException("Directory not found: " + sdir);
            }

            Set<String> modifiedPaths = new HashSet<String>();
            List<File> modifiedFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
            Set<String> deletedPaths = new HashSet<String>();
            List<File> deletedFileList = new ArrayList<File>();

            FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
            FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
            FileAlterationListenerAdaptor listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {
                // Is triggered when a file is created in the monitored folder
                @Override
                public void onFileCreate(File file) {

                    // "file" is the reference to the newly created file
                    try {
                        if(modifiedPaths.add(file.getCanonicalPath()))
                            modifiedFileList.add(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // Is triggered when a file is created in the monitored folder
                @Override
                public void onFileChange(File file) {

                    // "file" is the reference to the newly created file
                    try {
                        if(modifiedPaths.add(file.getCanonicalPath()))
                            modifiedFileList.add(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // Is triggered when a file is deleted from the monitored folder
                @Override
                public void onFileDelete(File file) {
                    try {
                        if(deletedPaths.add(file.getCanonicalPath()))
                            deletedFileList.add(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
```

AnalysePdf code:

```
package org.solr.extract.pdf;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * 
 *
 *
 */
public class AnalysePdf {

    /**
     * 
     * @param pdffolder
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void analysePdfFolder(String pdffolder) throws IOException {
        String htmout = "";

        File dir = new File(pdffolder);

        if (dir.isDirectory() == false) {
            System.out.println("Pdf Dir does not exists : " + pdffolder);
            return;
        }

        // list out all the file name and filter by the extension
        String[] list = dir.list();

        if (list.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Pdf Dir no files end with : " + pdffolder);
            return;
        }

        for (String pdffilename : list) {

            if (!pdffilename.endsWith(".pdf"))
                continue;

            int dotpos = pdffilename.lastIndexOf(".");

            String pdfsubname = pdffilename.substring(0, dotpos);

            String pdfpagepath = pdffolder + pdfsubname + File.separator;

            String pdffullname = pdffolder + pdffilename;

            htmout = pdffullname.replace(".pdf", ".htm");

            if (new File(htmout).exists())
                continue;

            // Split pages of one pdf

            ReadPdf.Splitepages(pdffullname, pdfpagepath);

            // Extract subpages
            ReadPdf.AnalysisFolder(pdfpagepath);

            // Merge subpages to one htm
            ReadPdf.MergePages(htmout, pdfpagepath);

            FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(pdfpagepath));

        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param file_list
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void analyseListPdf(List<File> list, String tmpDir) throws IOException {

        String htmout = "";

        if (list.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files");     
            return;
        }

        for (File file : list) {

            if (!file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".pdf"))
                continue;

            // create splited pdfs in tmpDir\pdfname directory
            String pdfpagepath = tmpDir + File.separator + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")) + File.separator;

            // create html files in tempDir directory
            htmout = tmpDir + File.separator + file.getName().replace(".pdf", ".htm");

            if (new File(htmout).exists())
                continue;

            // Split pages of one pdf
            ReadPdf.Splitepages(file.getAbsolutePath(), pdfpagepath);

            // Extract subpages
            ReadPdf.AnalysisFolder(pdfpagepath);

            // Merge subpages to one htm
            ReadPdf.MergePages(htmout, pdfpagepath);

            FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(pdfpagepath));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're iterating through the pages in the PDF, don't you already have the page number available? You usually retrieve the pages through something like `List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();`

Comment: Could I send you the tool so you can take a look because I feel stuck at the moment is not much there @MatsLindh

Comment: No. Add any relevant code to the question, together with what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @MatsLindh added the main function

Comment: Seems like your tool has a function that converts all PDFs to HTML and then submit that content to Solr. You'll have to dig into `AnalysePdf.analysePdfFolder(dir);` and use the actual PDF information instead of the converted HTML.

Comment: @MatsLindh I added the code for Analyse if you can please take a look and let me know your opinion

Comment: Your Analyze function explicitly extracts each page by itself, then merges them to a single html document at the end - if you want to parse each page by itself, don't do that - and keep the page number as part of the file name.

Comment: Ok I will try to make some changes